# Cannot draw a filled circle with SDL2 gfx

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

There is the following code. The desired result is that a window is created and a filled circle is drawn:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h>

int main()
{
   SDL_Window* window = nullptr;
   SDL_Renderer* renderer = nullptr;

   if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
   {
      std::cout << "Could not initialise" << std::endl;
      return 1;
   }

   window = SDL_CreateWindow("MyGame",
                             SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                             SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                             640,
                             480,
                             SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
   if(!window)
   {
      std::cout << "Could not create the window" << std::endl;
      return 1;
   }

   renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
   SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

   Sint16 circleR = 100;
   Sint16 circleX = 300;
   Sint16 circleY = 300;
   SDL_Surface* windowSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
   Uint32 circleColour = SDL_MapRGB(windowSurface->format, 255, 0, 0);

   int result = filledCircleColor(renderer, circleX, circleY, circleR, circleColour);

   std::cout << "drawing the circle r " << circleR << " x " << circleX << " y " << circleY << " circleColour " << circleColour << std::endl;
   std::cout << "draw circle result " << result << std::endl;

   SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

   bool run = true;
   while(run)
   {
      SDL_Event event;
      while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
      {
         if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
         {
            run = false;
         }
      }

   }

   SDL_Quit();
   return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the circle is not drawn - the window is all black.

The output:

```
drawing the circle r 100 x 300 y 300 circleColour 16711680
draw circle result 0
```

`filledCircleColor` returns 0 what should mean that there's no error.

What should be done so that the circle is drawn? I'm using SDL 2.0.2 on Ubuntu with SDL2 gfx extension.

Comment: You are not using `windowSurface`.

Comment: Do you mean that I don't call `filledCircleColor` on `windowSurface`? As I see in docs it was changed since SDL1.2 - `filledCircleColor` takes as a first parameter a renderer instead of a surface. Or did you mean anything else?

Comment: No that was what I meant. That change must have been after my latest SDL endeavours. Try finding a recent example, surely there are some out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About `SDL_GetWindowSurface`, [the documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSurface?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryVideo%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29) says : "You may not combine this with 3D or the rendering API on this window."

For me, in your example, `SDL_GetWindowSurface` returns null.

The [`filledCircleColor()`](http://www.ferzkopp.net/Software/SDL2_gfx/Docs/html/_s_d_l2__gfx_primitives_8h.html#ab973fd9868527fb13078c356d4a9c6f7) function takes a color of the form 0xRRGGBBAA.

It works after removing the surface part, and changing to :

```
int result = filledCircleColor(renderer, circleX, circleY, circleR, 0xFF0000FF);
```

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that this behaviour occurs because alpha channel was set to 0, then this circle was drawn but it was not visible. There is also a second function in the API of gfx - `filledCircleRGBA` which lets you specify RGBA directly and solves the problem.