# SDL2_gfx screen filled after second loop

Tags: c++, c, sdl, sdl-2

So when this code taken from [Cannot draw a filled circle with SDL2 gfx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133297/cannot-draw-a-filled-circle-with-sdl2-gfx):

```
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

Sint16 circleR = 100;
Sint16 circleX = 300;
Sint16 circleY = 300;

int result = filledCircleColor(renderer, circleX, circleY, circleR, 0xFF0000FF);

//std::cout << "drawing the circle r " << circleR << " x " << circleX << " y " << circleY << " circleColour " << circleColour << std::endl;
std::cout << "draw circle result " << result << std::endl;

SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

runs only once, it properly draws a circle. However, if it loops around and executes it a second, time, the screen fills with the color's circle, which in this case is red. The same effect happens on all the other functions. How can you ensure a proper circle is drawn on multiple loops and not a window full of color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the clear color with  `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor` before your call to `SDL_RenderClear`. Otherwise the color you set while drawing your circle will still be the active draw color and you'll fill the entire render area with it.